# Combing AND and OR conditions with getResources tvFilters?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-getresources

I am combining a form and PHP to create a kind of search.

I am using getResources' tvFilters to show the results of the search, eg:

```
echo '[[!getResources? &parents=`[[42]]` &tpl=`NewProdTpl` &includeTVs=`1` &includeContent=`1` &limit=`99` &tvFilters=`' . $filters .'`]]';
```

This works somewhat. But I need to figure out a way to use combined AND and OR conditions, like in SQL, eg:

```
SELECT supplier_id
FROM suppliers
WHERE (name = 'IBM')
OR (name = 'Hewlett Packard' AND city = 'Atlantic City')
OR (name = 'Gateway' AND status = 'Active' AND city = 'Burma');
```

Obviously I have tried using brackets like:

```
$filters = '(Type==Forklift),(Brand==Iseki||Brand==Kubota)';
```

But I have had no luck.

Would anyone know if there is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think tvFilters needs brackets, have you tried this (OR delimiter first):

```
$filters = 'Brand==Iseki||Brand==Kubota,Type==Forklift';
```

You could also try adding a wildcard:

```
$filters = 'Brand==%Iseki%||Brand==%Kubota%,Type==%Forklift%';
```